# Problem between Table Rates and Klarna on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, klarna

- I installed fresh Magento 2 and after that I installed Sample Data to have some products.
- I entered the settings: Stores > Configuration > Sales > Table Rates
- I enabled it, I set the Condition to "Price vs Destination"
- "Show Method if Not Applicable" to "yes"
- I imported CSV with postcodes data
- Cache Flush
- I entered to my store and I added some products to cart
- On checkout I see in Shipping Methods Table Rate, Flat Rate, Free Shipping  with correct price
- I installed Klarna and configured it (playground mode)
- I disabled Klarna Payment and enabled Klarna Checkout
- The same: I added some products to cart, go to checkout
- Klarna Checkout is loading perfectly
- Everything is fine, but one thing: there are shipping methods Flat Rate and Free Shipping (Table Rate is missing)

It may be conflict between Magento and Klarna?

I was searching on settings but I dodn't find anything.